# Rewrite urls ending with _word.html into ?word

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite a url via .htaccess so that urls ending with:

```
_slides.html
```

become accessible via

```
?slides
```

a typical url looks like this on the server:

```
website.com/directory1/_slides.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to rewrite *"/`$any`/_slides.html"* into *"/`$any`/?slides"* ? Then please try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/_slides.html$ /$1/?slides [L]
```

Or the opposite? Like this *(for I'm confused in your question)*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/\?slides$ /$1/_slides.html [L]
```

---

**Last Attempt**

Now I know that you want to view *"/`$any`/?slides"* with the content of *"/`$any`/slides_html"*, now try to make sure that your *.htaccess* file is located in the root of your domain and try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slides$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/$ /$1/_slides.html [L]
```

If these directives didn't work, then it's not possible for a dynamic directory with query string to be rewritten.

Comment: neither works. _slides.html part is constant. I want to rewrite all urls that end with file name _slides.html

Comment: yes, i want to rewrite "/$any/_slides.html" into "/$any/?slides" . so i'm using your top suggestion, and when i access "website.com/dir1/?slides" i get served the directory index "website.com/dir1" not "website.com/dir1/_slides.html". any ideas? i use only your instructions in the .htaccess.

Comment: @Dan Did you try the second suggestion? If not, then try it and tell me the result.

Comment: Tried, the same result - the directory is served - not the _slides.html file

Comment: wow, man , it works! the last attempt works! you are a super guru!

Comment: @Dan Remember that always accept an answer on _SO_ if it solved your problem to make the library organized.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/])*/$ /$1/_%1.html [L]
```

That should take a request like `http://website.com/directory1/?slides` and serve the content at `/directory1/_slides.html`.

To redirect direct access to `_` files, you can also add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^/]*)/_([^.\ \?]+)\.html(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/?%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: it currently returns me the error: The requested URL /t/_slides.html was not found on this server. not sure when /t/ appeared from, as i cleaned the .htaccess just for this entry you proposed - the first one

Comment: @Dan what's the URL you are accessing and what are you expecting to get served?

Comment: I'm accessing: website.com/directory1/?slides and i'm expecting to get this url served there: website.com/directory1/_slides.html

Comment: @Dan no idea there the `/t/` is coming from. When I test those rules in a blank htaccess file, I clearly get routed to `/directory1/_slides.html`.

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I left out a `?` in the second rule, though I don't think that's got anything to do with your issue

Comment: I get page NOT found error when accessing via website.com/dir/?slides